# Toggle Switch Help

Tags: switches

I'm trying to connect this Toggle Switch to my Pi 
[image]

But I can't seem to get any input off it, It's connected to a GPIO pin and ground like I've done with Push Buttons in the past but it just doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: We are going to need to see pictures of the rest of the connections and your code.

Comment: Do you have a way to test the switch without the Pi to rule it out as the problem? E.g. test with a ohm-meter or wire a LED with resistor and a power source via the switch.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I had an error in my GPIO setup, I had the wrong GPIO.PUD_UP set.

`GPIO.setup(LG_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)`

Working fine with the code above now :)